# How to send from ESP32 to Arduino?

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am using ESP32 to read a temperature sensor and I wont to send this reading to Arduino to act according to different reading

what should be the connection between the ESP32 and Aruido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should is not the appropriate word, I *would* suggest to use the UART (Serial.print() and Serial.read()).
Because the ESP has an operating voltage of 3.3V and Arduino 5V, you must use a [level shifter](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide/all).